# How to run NUnit tests with Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6?

Tags: nunit, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

We have been focusing on the new JavaScript capabilities of Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 for the past few weeks. We were sorta expecting other basic .NET aspects to just work.

Today, we just tried to add some Unit Tests using [NUnit](http://nunit.org) to a WebAPI project and we are 0 for 20 (since it's opening day!) No matter what we try, we can't seem to even be able to add a NuGet package reference to NUnit (including 2.6.4 and 3.0.0-beta1).

**Anybody have any suggestions on how to get NUnit tests to work with against ASP.NET 5 WebAPI projects?**

Here is what we are doing:

[image: VS2015 About box]

Adding the new 4.6 ASP.NET 5 project

[image: VS2015 Add new ASPNET 5 project]

We are interested in the WebAPI stuff:

[image: VS2015 ASPNET 5 project config]

We read about issues with NuGet Package manager from [NuGet Beta2](http://blog.nuget.org/20150226/nuget-3.0-beta2.html), so we installed that version. And updated our configuration:

[image: VS2015 NuGet configuration]

We can find the NUnit package (3.0 beta)

[image: VS2015 NUnit NuGet page]

But in the end, this is all we get in the output window:

[image: VS2015 NUnit NuGet output]

And the references are missing:

[image: Missing NUnit references]

Here is our Project.json for this project:

```js
{
  /* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "NUnit": "3.0.0-beta-1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use xUnit ?

Comment: can you share your project.json ?

Comment: @aguafrommars our company has thousands of Unit tests written with NUnit. With the significant changes coming with ASP.NET and VS2015, we can't afford to retrain all our devs on a different test platform also at this point. I have added our project.json (it's fairly simple - fresh project)

Comment: do you find it in `kpm restore` output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it turns out that my PostSharp NuGet source was messing with NuGet. I disabled it and things started working.
[image: VS2015 NuGet sources]

I now have NUnit 3.0 Beta 1 available:
[image: NUnit 3.0 beta 1 NuGet output]
[image: NUnit 3.0 beta 1 Reference OK]

I suspect this is or will be fixed in a recent release of PostSharp or the Package Source.

Comment: weird. thanks for sharing your solution. I was trying to repo your issue with no success :D

Comment: I guess, to clarify, it's any source that errors out will cause this. It seems odd that, even though it does find the package and it is not from a "bad" source, it still fails. But at least for now, I can move ahead with NUnit and VS2015.

Comment: Did you actually get this running with Visual Studio 2015, Nunit 3, and resharper?  Or did you use a different runner?

Comment: @DRobertE, I must apologize. I have not been in that area since this was posted. I changed companies and we're not on NUnit 3 yet... best of luck.